# StartCoroutine is not work in process.Exited in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

i call process
I call function it when the process dies

IEnumeratorLoadImageSet is being called startcorutine but it is not called

If startcorutine is commented out, this loop goes well, but if not commented out, this loop is called only once and stops.

```
 public void StartProcess(string path)
    {
        process= DI.Process.Start(path);
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        process.Exited += (obj, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(2);
            string str=ReadFile();
            string[] arrStr=str.Split(' ');
            for(int i=0; i<arrStr.Length-1;i++)
            {
                Debug.Log(arrStr.Length);
                FileInfo fileInfo=new FileInfo(arrStr[i]);
                importImage.LoadImageBut(arrStr[i], fileInfo.Name,fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
            }
        };
```

```
 public void LoadImageBut(string filePath,string fileNames,DateTime dateTime)
    {
        fileName = fileNames;
        fileInfo = dateTime.ToString();
        Debug.Log(filePath);
        //this part 
        StartCoroutine(LoadImageSet(filePath));
    
    }
```

```
IEnumerator LoadImageSet(string filePath)
    {
        Debug.Log(33);
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(dataPath))
        {
            yield return null;
             yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uwr.error))
            {
                tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
        }
}
```

StartCoroutine(LoadImageSet(filePath))
If you call it from start, it goes well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `StartCoroutiune` from a MonoBehaviour's Start or Awake method.

StartCoroutine is meant to be used from the main thread, start the Coroutine from somewhere in the unity object life-cycle such as a MonoBehaviour's Awake() or Start() method, and it should work fine. By subscribing to the process.Exit delegate, the resulting code occurs off the unity main thread where coroutines won't work.

To avoid this problem, might I suggest something like the following:

```cs
public class ImageLaoder : MonoBeaviour {
   private Queue<string> _imageQueue;
   private ImageLoader Instance {get; private set;}

   public static void LoadImage(string dataPath) => 
       Instance._imageQueue.Enqueue(dataPath);

   IEnumerator Start(){
       Instance = this;
       while(true){
         yield return null;
         if(_imageQueue.Any()){
            var nextImage = _imageQueue.Dequeue();
            StartCoroutine(LoadImageSet(nextImage));
         }
       }
   }

   IEnumerator LoadImageSet(string filePath){...}
}
```

Now you can call ImageLoader.LoadImage(dataPath) off the main thread, and the MonoBehaviour's coroutine will pick up the work and process it on the main thread, where your LoadImageSet coroutine works again.